# Wavelet Transform Modulus Maxima (WTMM) method

Tags: signal-processing, fractals, wavelet-analysis

Has anyone already coded the Wavelet Transform Modulus Maxima (WTMM) method for computing the singular spectrum using [multi fractal formalism](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Wavelet-based_multifractal_analysis) in *Mathematica*?

The goal is to analyse 1D, 2D and 3D data. See, e.g., [LastWave](http://www.cmap.polytechnique.fr/~bacry/LastWave/) (a signal processing oriented command language) and MATLAB (see [wavelab](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~wavelab/)).

I've added links to two papers discussing the WTMM method and algorithms:

1. [Singularity spectrum of fractal signals from wavelet analysis: Exact results](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01053588)
2. [Determination of the Hurst exponent by use of wavelet transforms](http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevE.58.2779)

Comment: Thanks Doc; this ought to be useful to potential answerers…